# Django how to get values by user_ID

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all of a users reports and pass them to the page template. My question is how do I filter by user_id=1?

**views.py**

```
data = report.objects.values()
return render(request,'list.html',data)
```

**models.py**

```
class user(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    accountlevel = models.BigIntegerField(default=1)
    reportsCreated = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

class report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    dateran = models.DateField()
    fromdate = models.DateField()
    todate = models.DateField()
    state = models.IntegerField()
    graphURL = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    reporttype = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py you can filter values by user id.

Refer following code

```
data = report.objects.filter(user__id=your_user_id).values()
return render(request,'list.html',data)
```

Comment: thanks, getting the below error, context must be a dict rather than QuerySet.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, I was missing the context,

```
data = Report.objects.filter(user__id=1).values()
context = {'data': data}
return render(request,'list.html',context)
```

Thank you call for your help :)